# DDD and MVC in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design

I'm totally confused.

Laravel structure is MVC, but recently I heard that sometimes developers use DDD in laravel.

- What's point of that?
- Any example for using DDD in MVC?

I tried to find some Laravel projects used DDD but didn't get any results

Comment: The tag `[data-driven-design]` states the following: *"Note that conceptual DDD questions are better to be asked at softwareengineering.stackexchange.com"* - Did you try asking there?

Comment: No I'm not. But i will do it soon after your suggestion, thanks 

Comment: Excellent. Personally, I've never even heard of Domain Driven Design before, but from a quick glance, it's a pretty broad concept that you could easily adapt a Laravel application to use this. Instead of standard methods like `store`, `create`, `update`, etc., you'd define things like `withdraw`, `deposit`, etc. (for a banking application), or Models like `Account`, `Transaction`, etc. But yeah, I would expect you'd get better traction and better answers if you migrated this question to that Stackexchange site.

Comment: MVC is one of those buzzwords that mean almost nothing.  Controller has a more or less standard definition but most folks suggest minimal code in controllers. Model is just a vague term meaning your app uses data in some fashion. And view can mean anything you want.  For whatever reason PHP framework developers feel compelled to describe their framework as MVC. Except for one. Oddly enough, arguably the most admired framework Symfony somehow survives as being just a request/response framework.  And DDD is something else completely. No relation to MVC.

Comment: @mahdimsr have a look at this approach, it is exactly what you are looking for. I did use a similar implementation and it is awesome for big projects or very quickly changing projects: https://www.youtube.com/live/0Rq-yHAwYjQ?si=oKQPkHHs-e3pfEAt&t=4059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the application is in its early stages and going for microservice architecture isn't the best choice but we might need to scale the project sooner or later. In these scenarios personally, I prefer DDD. So with a good implementation of DDD, we can separate different business logic in a monolith application until the need for scaling.

I once used DDD in a laravel application. I created a `Domain` folder inside the `app` folder. For every domain that I had, I created a folder with a mini-laravel app inside them(including controllers, configs, routes, services, etc.) So I had a project that was ready to split into smaller services in case of scaling.

The tricky part was implementing the infrastructure. We usually have a lot of shared codes between these domains(e.g. events, notifications, etc.) so I needed to write all of these codes in `Infrastructure` folder and use them like some packages, and again in case of scaling, I copied the whole folder into the new service.

Also other than the need for scaling, sometimes we have a big monolith application with +100 controllers. Handling them in standard laravel architecture will be a disaster. In those cases going for DDD might be a good idea for better maintainability.

Comment: Good answer, but it is something vage, you need to add a real example of a tree so it is more understandable

Comment: That's what I needed to hear. good job !

Comment: @matiaslauriti I agree. Do you have any idea how to demonstrate it? Should I add a picture? or a file tree in text format? Do you have any examples so I can adapt?